# Jenkins and SonarQube for Pipeline Gating without using the SonarQube Jenkins Plugin in bash

Tags: bash, jenkins, sonarqube

We have a build that runs SonarQube from Jenkins using a bash script, and we want to get the results of the tests back in the Jenkins pipeline so we can prevent merges on fail.  We are using v2 of Jenkins, but it is an old version that doesn't support the SonarQube Jenkins plugin, and upgrading Jenkins isn't something we can accomplish in our sprint.

Is there is a way to get the results to gate our pipeline with what we have?  At the moment this is how we're running SonarQube from Jenkins in OpenShift.

```sh
dotnet build
~/.dotnet/tools/coverlet "./bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/AppTests.dll" --target "dotnet" --targetargs 'test . --no-build --logger "trx;LogFileName=TestResults.trx" --logger "xunit;LogFileName=TestResults.xml" --results-directory ../BuildReports/UnitTests' -f opencover -o ./BuildReports/Coverage/coverage
dotnet build-server shutdown

~/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-sonarscanner begin /k:${APP_NAME} /n:${APP_NAME} /d:sonar.host.url=${SONAR_URL} /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="./BuildReports/Coverage/coverage.opencover.xml" /d:sonar.exclusions="**/Migrations/*" /d:sonar.coverage.exclusions="**Tests*.cs","**/Migrations/*","**/Program.cs" /d:sonar.cpd.exclusions="**/Migrations/*" /d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths="./BuildReports/UnitTests/TestResults.trx" /d:sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths="./BuildReports/UnitTests/TestResults.xml"
dotnet build -v n

~/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-sonarscanner end
dotnet build-server shutdown
```

Comment: One way you can try is that Sonarqube is rich with web api’s. You can use the quality gate api to get the status of quality gate and parse the json output to get the status.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Build Breaker plugin on the SonarQube server. And enable it for the project you are scanning -- to do this go to Project Settings on the SonarQube server. You may need server level and project level Administrative rights for doing this.
Now the Sonar Scanner will check for the quality gate status after doing the code analysis. In case the quality gate fails, the scanner returns with a non-zero status code that can be used to mark the build as “failed”.
https://github.com/adnovum/sonar-build-breaker#sonarqube-build-breaker-plugin

In case you don't have control over what gets installed on the SonarQube server, then you may write a bash script to use the curl command to hit web API of your SonarQube server to first find if the analysis report has been processed by the SonarQube server and then the quality gate status of the code analysis just concluded.
For the documentation of the web API, see `http://<sonarqube-server-host>/web_api`.